# Ruby on Rails broken on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to run the following command and it says there is nothing to update:

```
adam-lees-macbook-3:ART Adam$ sudo gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update
```

But I know it's not true because I get this:

```
adam-lees-macbook-3:ART Adam$ gem -v
1.2.0
```

Then I tried this:

```
adam-lees-macbook-3:ART Adam$ sudo gem install rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-1.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for rubygems-update-1.3.5...
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
Could not find main page README
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the following:

1. Nuked my MacPorts install
2. Reinstalled everything

And everything seems to be ok.

There's an interesting blog post (http://blog.d27n.com/2009/08/26/mac-os-x-snow-leopard-rails-mysql-and-sphinx/) which has a bit more information.

If you're problem is just rubygems you might be able to get away with downloading rubygems and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem with upgrading RubyGems. This is how I fixed it:

1. First update to rubygems_update version 1.3.1

   sudo gem install -r rubygems-update -v 1.3.1
2. Then upgrade RubyGems to 1.3.1

   sudo update_rubygems
3. Then you can use gem update --system to upgrade to RubyGems version 1.3.5

   sudo gem update --system
4. Check that correct RubyGems version is installed.

   $ gem -v

   1.3.5

After that you might also need to upgrade your gems. Please see "[upgrading-to-snow-leopard](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/30/upgrading-to-snow-leopard)" (a blog on rubyonrails.org)